# Returning a React Element within a Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am fairly new to React and trying to edit a former coworker's code (hence the non-traditional React style).

I need to return a series of buttons (here "Hello" and "Goodbye") when a single button ("Dropdown") is clicked. In order to make this more dynamic down the line, I'd like to return those buttons from a function (dropdownDetails) rather than [show,setShow] variables, etc.

When I run this code, the console shows that dropdownDetails is triggered, but "Hello" and "Goodbye" don't appear in the UI. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
///// In base.js:
const e = React.createElement;

///// in page_body.js:
function pageBody(props) {

    const dropdownDetailsWrap = (props) => (e) => {
      console.log("Wrap triggered")
      dropdownDetails()
    }
    
    function dropdownDetails() {
        console.log("dropdownDetails useEffect triggered")
        return( 
            e("button",{type:"button"},"Hello"),
            e("button",{type:"button"},"Goodbye")
             );
    };
    
    const pageBody = () => (e) => {
    return(
        e("button", {type:"button",onClick:dropdownDetailsWrap(),className:'btn'},"Dropdown")
        )}
    }

ReactDOM.render(e(pageBody), document.querySelector('#page_body'));
```

Note: I know there are more elegant ways to make a dropdown, particularly using packages. Just trying to understand the basics with pure React for now.

Comment: You are returning the two jsx elements thats it.
I mean to say that,  once you return those , you never use them to render them on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the response - not sure I know how to fix it though. I was thinking it through like this: dropdownDetailsWrap is called in pageBody, which is rendered. Because dropdownDetailsWrap calls the function dropdownDetails, the result of the function (the two jsx elements) must be rendered as well. Since that's not correct, can you show me in the code how I am meant to render those elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can do like this provided you use the useState hook of react.

Wihtout using state, I doubt we can do this.

I am pasting the code below, check it out on codesandbox to explore more.

Here is the link [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-almeida-2rbei?file=/src/App.)

Code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const e = React.createElement;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PageBody />
    </div>
  );
}

function PageBody(props) {
  var buttonsToShow;
  const [showButtons, setshowButtons] = useState(false);
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([]);

  const dropdownDetailsWrap = (props) => {
    console.log("Wrap triggered");
    buttonsToShow = dropdownDetails();
    setButtons(buttonsToShow);
    setshowButtons(true);
  };

  function dropdownDetails() {
    console.log("dropdownDetails useEffect triggered");
    return [
      e("button", { type: "button", key: 1 }, "Hello"),
      e("button", { type: "button", key: 2 }, "Goodbye")
    ];
  }

  var dropbutton = () => {
    return e(
      "button",
      { type: "button", onClick: dropdownDetailsWrap, className: "btn" },
      "Dropdown"
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {dropbutton()} <br /> {showButtons && buttons}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now,I know this is not the best version but still you can clean this code and use the logic. Also by using state your code does not become static, moreover you get to customize more things,

Comment: Thanks so much! This works and helps me understand the render. To maintain consistency, I changed lines 40 to 44 to the following: `        e("button", {type:"button",onClick:dropdownDetailsWrap(),className:'btn'},"Dropdown"),
        e("div",{},loadScenarios),`